# Why is the output of this polymorphism program shows 0 in this Java program?

Tags: java

I am trying to integrate the topics like Dynamic Polymorphism, Inheritance and switch statements altogether in a single program where, I am getting an output but the result is always 0 in the console window. There is no error too. May be it is a logical error but I am not sure. I am just at the beginning phase of learning Java.

````
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
// Dynamic Polymorphism implementation with switch case
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        
        Shapes myShape = new Shapes();
        Shapes myTriangle = new Triangle();
        Shapes myCircle = new Circle();
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the Shape you would like to get the area of: ");
        System.out.println("Your Choices are : 1=Triangle, 2= Circle"); 
        int response = scanner.nextInt();
        switch(response)
        {
        case 1 : System.out.println("Enter the base of the triangle: ");
                 scanner.nextDouble();
                 System.out.println("Enter the height of the triangle: ");
                 scanner.nextDouble();
                 System.out.println(myTriangle.area());
        break;
        case 2 : System.out.println("Enter the radius of the circle: ");
                 scanner.nextDouble();
                 System.out.println(myCircle.area());
        break;
        default : System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                System.out.println(myShape.area());
        }
        scanner.close();
        }
    }
    class Shapes {
        double base;
        double height;
        double radius;
    
        public double area() {
            System.out.println("Formula for Area of triangle is 1/2 * base * height");
            System.out.println("Formula for Area of Circle is 3.14 * radius * radius");
            return 0;
        
        }
    
    }
    class Triangle extends Shapes{
    
        double x = 0.5*base*height;
    
        @Override
        public double area() {
        
            System.out.println("Area of Triangle is : ");
            return x;
        }
    
    }
    class Circle extends Shapes{
        double y = 3.14*radius*radius;
    
        @Override
        public double area() {
            System.out.println("Area of Circle is:  ");
            return y;
        }

    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to assign value to the base, height, and radius i.e. you missed something like this:

```
myTriangle.base = scanner.nextDouble();
```

Secondly, your area() method should compute on the fly. Otherwise, the area value will always be 0, as originally all the base, height, and radios are 0. So for Triangle class, it should be like this:

```
class Triangle extends Shapes {
    @Override
    public double area() {
        System.out.println("Area of Triangle is : ");
        return 0.5 * base * height;
    }
}
```

You should do the same for Circle.